# Fisheye/Crucible syntax highlighting for Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, syntax-highlighting, atlassian-fisheye, atlassian-crucible

As of Crucible version 4.2.1, there is no built-in syntax highlight support for Kotlin files. I have already filled a [feature request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CRUC-8061) for that.

However, for now, the only possibility is to add a custom syntax config as described [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/fishkb/configure-syntax-highlighting-for-non-standard-file-extensions-300811223.html).

Has anyone already done it and can share the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating this file by myself. It's based on Java config but uses Kotlin keywords.

This [project](https://github.com/zbigniew-malinowski/krucible) contains also a script to generate a prefix tree of keywords, if you don't like the list I'm using.

Below you can find the file's contents:

```
syntaxdef kotlin {


/\s+/m : ;
#keywords
/(a(bstract|nnotation|s)|break|c(atch|lass|o(mpanion|n(st|tinue))|rossinline)\
|d(ata|elegate|o|ynamic)|e(lse|num|xternal)|f(i(eld|le|nally)|or|un|alse)|get\
|i(f|mport|n(fix|it|line|terface)|s|t)|n(oinline|ull)|o(bject|pe(n|rator)|ut)\
|p(a(ckage|ram)|roperty)|re(ceiver|ified|turn)|s(e(aled|tparam)|u(per|spend))\
|t(ailrec|h(is|row)|r(y|ue)|ype(alias|of))|va(l|rarg)|wh(en|ile))\b/ : {
      region {
        type=keyword;
        index=word;
      }
}

/[\p{L}_\$][\p{L}\p{N}_\$]*/ : {
      region {
         type=identifier;
         index=word;
      }
  }

#annotation
/@[\p{L}_\$][\p{L}\p{N}_\$]*/ : {
      region {
         type=annotation;
         index=word;
      }
  }


# string literals
/"/ : {
    context {
            /\\"/: ;
            /\\./: ;
            /$/m : exit;
            "\"" : exit;
        }
        region ${ALL} {
               type=string;
        }
    }

# char literal
/'/ : {
    context {
            /\\./: ;
            /$/m : exit;
            "'" : exit;
        }
        region ${ALL} {
               type=char_literal;
        }
    }


/\/\/.*$/m : {
      todo(${0});
      region {
         type=comment;
         index=prose;
         findlinks=true;
      }
   }


/\/\*\*(.*?)\*\//s : {
      javadoc(${1});
      region {
         type=comment;
         index=prose;
         findlinks=true;
      }
   }

   context javadoc {

      /(\B@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)\s*([^@\*]*)/ : {
         region ${1} {
            type=commentmeta;
         }
      }
   }

/(0x[0-9a-f][0-9a-f_]*l?)|(0b[0-1][0-1_]*l?)|([0-9][0-9_]*(\.[0-9][0-9_]*)?|\.[0-9][0-9_]+)(e(\+|-)?[0-9][0-9_]*)?(f|l|d)?/i : {
       region {
          type=numeric;
       }
   }

/\/\*(.*?)\*\//s : {
      todo(${1});
      region {
         type=comment;
         findlinks=true;
      }
      region ${1} {
         index=prose;
      }
   }

   context todo {
      /(?i)todo\s.*/ : {
        region {
          type=todo;
        }
      }

   }

}
```